# What was the physical environment like in the Fertile Cresent between 10k BCE and 1 CE?

Tags: climate-change, climate

Mesopotamia was part of the Fertile Crescent, and [Assur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assur) was an Assyrian city in Mesopotamia for roughly 1500 years, but it looks like [this](https://whc.unesco.org/en/list/1130/) now (barely any vegetation, pure desert):

[image]

What was the Fertile Crescent like 10k BCE (or even before that) until it became a desert like this? Was it in fact "flowing streams and lush vegetation" at one point? Where can I find more description of the environment during this time, and why it changed. Wondering next, if it *was* lush with streams and vegetation, why it became a desert.

I am new to digging into the ancient Near East, but haven't found anything saying what it was really possibly like back then.